# Arithmetic sum of matrix of every row only for numbers who are divided by 3

Tags: c, matrix

Need some help guys, don't know how to do an arithmetic sum of rows only for the numbers that are divided by 3. Example for a 3x3 matrix , output should be only 3 numbers 15,12,10 . Here is my code i made it to work only calculating the arithmetic sum of rows. Thus finding the middle number of every row.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main ()
{
int a[10][10],m,n,i,j,sum;

double am[10];
printf("Enter order of matrix ");
scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
printf("Enter values of matrix\n");

for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
{
 sum=0;

 for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
 {
  printf("Enter value of a[%d][%d] ",i,j);
  scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);

  if(a[i][j]%3==0)
    sum=sum+a[i][j];
 }

 am[i]=(double)sum/n;
}

for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
{
  printf("\nArithmetic Mean of row %d = %f",i,am[i]);
}

getch();
}
```

Comment: "15,12,10". Are you sure?

Comment: Just an example of what it should look like lol , the output should be 3 arithmetic sums of every row . @Bathsheba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
```

and

```
for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
```

to

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
```

These are done because array indices start from 0 and end at `length-1` and not from 1 to `length`. Also do the same for the last loop. Also,it is better to add a check to see if `m` and `n` are more than 10.